# use node-redis with node 8 util.promisify

Tags: node.js, redis, promise

node -v : 8.1.2

I use redis client [node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) with node 8 util.promisify , no blurbird.

the callback redis.get is ok, but promisify type get error message

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'internal_send_command' of undefined
>       at get (D:\Github\redis-test\node_modules\redis\lib\commands.js:62:24)
>       at get (internal/util.js:229:26)
>       at D:\Github\redis-test\app.js:23:27
>       at Object. (D:\Github\redis-test\app.js:31:3)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)

my test code

```
const util = require('util');

var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient({
        host: "192.168.99.100",
        port: 32768,
    });

let get = util.promisify(client.get);

(async function () {
    client.set(["aaa", JSON.stringify({
        A: 'a',
        B: 'b',
        C: "C"
    })]);

    client.get("aaa", (err, value) => {
        console.log(`use callback: ${value}`);
    });

    try {
        let value = await get("aaa");
        console.log(`use promisify: ${value}`);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`promisify error:`);
        console.log(e);
    }

    client.quit();
})()
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

changing `let get = util.promisify(client.get);`

to `let get = util.promisify(client.get).bind(client);`

solved it for me :)

Comment: thanks! it' solved，that is `this` problem  
[this.internal_send_command](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/blob/ff9b727609ea125919828f7373e40082fd432eec/lib/commands.js#L62) without bind `this` is undefined

Comment: @wiYu this solution of binding `this` would be required for any function you promisify which is on an object and internally uses a non lexically bound this.

Comment: just replace `client.get` with your favourite command ;)

Answer (score 7):

> If you are using node v8 or higher, you can promisify node_redis with
>   util.promisify as in:
>
> ```
> const {promisify} = require('util');
> const getAsync = promisify(client.get).bind(client); // now getAsync is a promisified version of client.get:
>
> // We expect a value 'foo': 'bar' to be present
> // So instead of writing client.get('foo', cb); you have to write:
> return getAsync('foo').then(function(res) {
>     console.log(res); // => 'bar'
> });
> ```
>
> or using async await:
>
> ```
> async myFunc() {
>     const res = await getAsync('foo');
>     console.log(res);
> }
> ```

culled shamelessly from [redis official repo](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#promises)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **Blue Bird** Library plus monkey patching will do the trick for you.
For example:

```js
const bluebird = require('bluebird')
const redis = require('redis')
async connectToRedis() {
     // use your url to connect to redis
     const url = '//localhost:6379'
     const client = await redis.createClient({
                url: this.url
            }) 
     client.get = bluebird.promisify(client.get).bind(client);
     return client
   }
// To connect to redis server and getting the key from redis
connectToRedis().then(client => client.get(/* Your Key */)).then(console.log)
```