# converting callback to async throws error

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, es6-promise, nodemailer

The following code works:

```
  var smtpConfig = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // use SSL
    selfSigned: true
  };

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);

  // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
  var mailOptions = {
    from: '"Some One" <someone@example.com>', // sender address
    to: 'validuser@company.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ?', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world ?</b>' // html body
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
          console.log(error);
      } else {
          console.log(info);
      }
  });
```

However, if I use `util.promisify` from node

```
  var sendMail = promisify(transporter.sendMail);
  var info = await sendMail(mailOptions);
```

I get an exception

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSocket' of undefined
  at sendMail (c:\Users\user\Source\project\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\mailer\index.js:143:25)
  at sendMail (internal/util.js:230:26)
```

problem is inside sendMail because 'this' is undefined:

```
/**
 * Sends an email using the preselected transport object
 *
 * @param {Object} data E-data description
 * @param {Function?} callback Callback to run once the sending succeeded or failed
 */
sendMail(data, callback) {
    let promise;

    if (!callback && typeof Promise === 'function') {
        promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            callback = shared.callbackPromise(resolve, reject);
        });
    }

    if (typeof this.getSocket === 'function') { <-- this is undefined
        this.transporter.getSocket = this.getSocket;
        this.getSocket = false;
    }
```

using util.promisify on plain functions works. I suppose this is because I use `util.promisify` on a class method.

Is there a way to achive this or do I need to extend the exting class with an `async function sendMail` overload

Comment: `util.promisify` can't possibly know what object `sendMail` previously was attached to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use node-redis with node 8 util.promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44815553/use-node-redis-with-node-8-util-promisify)

Comment: You are misusing `promisify`.  You'll need to bind context if you want to use it the way you are trying to.  `promisify` works really well with functional functions that don't need state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this particular case, you can use

```
await sendMail.call(transporter, mailOptions) // provide a context
```

Of course, looking at the source for `transporter.sendMail()`, it already supports invoking as a `then`able without wrapping in `util.promisify()`, so you can `await` it directly:

```
await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions) // omit callback to kick in promise-style async
```

Comment: Why the downvote? The duplicate target requires `util.promisfy()` while in this case it's helpful to know that's not necessary.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I'm pretty sure that you'll still need to `bind` the `transporter` in this case right?

Comment: @zero298 `sendMail`, the return value from `promisify()` is unbound. `.call()`ing it with `transporter` will invoke it with that as the context.

Comment: Well I don't know why the downvote but both solutions are correct. Thanks and thumbs up. Need to wait 5 minutes for accepting.

Comment: You're right, I was still stuck on `promisify` being used.  I didn't actually notice you were using `call`.